# using wget to get a certain web folder and save it to local linux server

Tags: linux, wget

I did a lot of search but couldn't find the suitable answer.
I just want to download everything recursively from http://somewebsite.com/images-and-docs to the current folder, while keeping source folder's entire structure. Which command should I use?

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/104488/how-to-recursively-download-an-entire-web-directory. That is if you specifically need to use wget for this task.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to download an entire Web site, perhaps for off-line viewing, wget can do the
job—for example:

> $ wget \ --recursive \ --no-clobber \ --page-requisites \
>   --html-extension \ --convert-links \ --restrict-file-names=windows \ --domains website.org \ --no-parent \ www.website.org/tutorials/html/

This command downloads the Web site www.website.org/tutorials/html/.

The options are:

--recursive: download the entire Web site.

--domains website.org: don't follow links outside website.org.

--no-parent: don't follow links outside the directory tutorials/html/.

--page-requisites: get all the elements that compose the page (images, CSS and so on).

--html-extension: save files with the .html extension.

--convert-links: convert links so that they work locally, off-line.

--restrict-file-names=windows: modify filenames so that they will work in Windows as well.

--no-clobber: don't overwrite any existing files (used in case the download is interrupted and
resumed).